# django migrations "LookupError: No installed app . . ." for initial data migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I want to provide initial data for user profile using migration. But somehow the app that I used to extend User models failed at lookup. The UserProfile class model is related one to one with auth.User & related One to many with class model from other app. Anyone have any idea to solved my problem?

- python version: 2.7
- django version: 1.8.11

Here's the traceback when doing testing:

```
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
  executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
  self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
  state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
  operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 183, in database_forwards
  self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
File "/home/pupil/Coding/estimator/IBES/ibes_initial_data/migrations/0001_ibes_initial_data_user_profile.py", line 6, in set_home_branch_user
  UserProfile = apps.get_model("users.UserProfile")
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 202, in get_model
  return self.get_app_config(app_label).get_model(model_name.lower())
File "/home/pupil/.virtualenvs/ibes18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 150, in get_app_config
  raise LookupError("No installed app with label '%s'." % app_label)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'users'.
```

Here's some of my code:

```
# 0001_initial_user_profile.py
from django.db import migrations


def set_profile_user(apps, schema_editor):
    Branch = apps.get_model("multiple", "Branch")
    UserProfile = apps.get_model("users", "UserProfile")
    User = apps.get_registered_model("auth", "User")
    user = User.objects.get(username="test_user")
    branch = Branch.objects.get(id=1)
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    UserProfile.objects.using(db_alias).create(
        user=user, home_branch=branch
    )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("multiple", "0001_initial"),
        ("auth", "0006_require_contenttypes_0002"),
        ("ibes_initial_data", "0001_ibes_initial_data_server")
    ]
    operations = [migrations.RunPython(set_home_branch_user)]


# users/models.py

...
class UserProfile(SynchronizableModel):
    from jobs.models.models_master import Merchant
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    home_branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
    max_jobs = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    merchant_access = models.ManyToManyField(Merchant)
...

# multiple/models.py

...
class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
...

# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
    'users',
...
)
```

Comment: Do you have an app called "users"? Show your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Comment: Yes, i have an app called users in my INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: djnago and python verson?

Comment: If you have it in your installed apps and still not getting it, then I think base directory might be wrongly set up, did you change it?

Comment: Python version is 2.7, django version is 1.8.11 & the directory location for users app is in the same directory as other apps. Other functionality regarding users app is working fine, but somehow initial data migration to fill data into users models is failed.